Pinescript indicator: why using current candle data (close) makes
The following script triggers a long Entry when the last closed Heiki Nashi is green and flat below. And triggers the exit if the current close price goes below the last low Heiki Nashi.
//@version=5
indicator(title="Tests repainting", overlay = true, max_labels_count = 500)

/////////////////// VARIABLES DEFINITION ///////////////////
ha_handle = ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid) 
ha_open = request.security(ha_handle, timeframe.period, open)
ha_close = request.security(ha_handle, timeframe.period, close)
ha_low = request.security(ha_handle, timeframe.period, low)
ha_high = request.security(ha_handle, timeframe.period, high)

timeAndDateInputBefore = input.time(timestamp("21 Apr 2024 14:15 +0100"), "Date départ")
timeAndDateInputAfter = input.time(timestamp("19 May 2024 15:00 +0100"), "Date arrivée")
bool barIsInRange = time > timeAndDateInputBefore and time < timeAndDateInputAfter

var is_bying = false
var is_selling = false
var entryLongCondition = false
var exitLongCondition = false

if barIsInRange

    entryLongCondition := ha_low[1] == ha_open[1] and not is_bying
    exitLongCondition := (close < ha_low[1]) and is_bying
    
    if entryLongCondition
        is_bying := true
        entryLongCondition := false
        alert("LONG ENTRY alert", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
    else if exitLongCondition
        is_bying := false
        exitLongCondition := false
        alert("LONG EXIT alert", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
plot(close)

The problem is that sometimes it triggers two Exit alerts in a row, which it should not do since I use the is_bying condition to check if we are already in a bying trade or not (so if is_bying is turned false at some point, then at the next tick, the exitLongCondition should not be turned true)

Any idea where the problem could come from?
